# New Device: Support Duration from Switch-on

Tags: samsung, updates

Having purchased a new Galaxy Tab s8 just recently, the question of would the 2027 software update curfew still hold, or will the clock for support start ticking once it is turned on, connected to the internet (and optionally registered)?

Experience with the older Galaxy Tab A S10.1 (2016) purchased in 2017 was positive, a generous 5 years, with the last update in early 2022. Because it had only occasional usage, functionality is not impaired in any way, and looks as if it could see out a couple more years at the very least.

Given that four years is the current figure for lifetime support, would switching on the new device then take it on to September 2027?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you switched it on is immaterial, the clock started when the device appeared in the market. If you purchase a device towards the end of it's support period, updates stop when the support period is over. [Samsung Security Updates](https://security.samsungmobile.com/workScope.smsb) clearly says

> And select devices launched in 2019 or later will be supported with firmware security updates for a minimum of four (4) years following their **global launch**...

(Emphasis added)

From a quick search your device was released in [February 22](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_S8). Your support period started from that date. In other words you have about two & half years of support left.

---

General Information that may be of use

See [Check this new tracker to see if your phone will get the next Android update](https://www.androidpolice.com/android-update-tracker-website/) and the [Android Update Tracker](https://www.androidupdatetracker.com/update-matrix).

Comment: Thanks, not easy to locate this info from the [product page](https://www.samsung.com/au/tablets/galaxy-tab-a/galaxy-tab-a8-wifi-dark-gray-128gb-sm-x200nzafxsa/) - serviceable lifetime of product is important.

Comment: @LaurieStearn Perhaps worth noting that the updates that the manufacturers provide are common to everyone (usually based on device model), not personalized (e.g. based on switched-on date). Thus there will be no updates to everyone since the manufacturers also stop creating new updates after that device model reaches the end of life.